# R to Extract <when> from Google MyTracks .kml file

Tags: r, kml

I would like to use R to read the "when" values from a .kml file created by Google My tracks (extract below):

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <Document>
 <open>1</open>
 <visibility>1</visibility>
 <name><![CDATA[2013-06-29 1:09pm]]></name>
 <atom:author><atom:name><![CDATA[Created by Google My Tracks on Android.]]></atom:name>     </atom:author>

 ...

 <gx:MultiTrack>
 <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
 <gx:interpolate>1</gx:interpolate>
 <gx:Track>
 <when>2013-06-29T17:09:04.564Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-79.305048 43.710639 72.9000015258789</gx:coord>
 <when>2013-06-29T17:09:06.135Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-79.304971 43.710653 67.4000015258789</gx:coord>
 <when>2013-06-29T17:09:08.135Z</when>
 <gx:coord>-79.305193 43.710535 78.19999694824219</gx:coord>
 <when>2013-06-29T17:09:09.135Z</when>
```

the node "when" is "a time value that corresponds to a position (specified in a gx:coord element)". "gx:coord" is " coordinate value consisting of three values for longitude, latitude, and altitude". (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtrack)

The path to the value I want is:

```
 kml/Document/Placemark/gx:MultiTrack/gx:Track/when
```

from: xmlstarlet el "filename.kml"

I was able to extract the coordinates and altitude using:

```
 coords <- xpathSApply(check, "//gx:coord", xmlValue)
 lat <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(coords)," "), "[",1)
 lon <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(coords)," "), "[",2)
 ele <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(coords)," "), "[",3)
```

but I have not been able to get at the time. What I'd like to pull out of the file is:

```
 17:09:04.564
 17:09:06.135
 17:09:08.135
 17:09:09.135
```

And line them up with the coordinates and elevation.

I have tried:

```
timeStamp <- xpathSApply(check, "//gx:MultiTrack", xmlValue)
```

that gets me a string that may be able to be parsed because the time starts with "T" and ends with "Z":

```
 [1] "absolute12013-06-29T17:09:04.564Z-79.305048 43.710639 72.90000152587892013-06-   29T17:09:06.135Z-79.304971 43.710653 67.40000152587892013-06-29T17:09:08.135Z-79.305193 43.710535 78.199996948242192013-06-29T17:09:09.135Z-79.305164 43.710592 77.699996948242192013-06-29T17:09:10.134Z-79.305097 43.710614 67.52013-06-29T17:09:11.137Z-79.305066 43.710572
```

Any bright ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit ----->

My inelegant solution:

```
 file_name <- "2013-06-29 1-09pm.kml"
 library(XML)
 # read XML tree schema
 check <-xmlInternalTreeParse(file=file_name)
 library(gsubfn)
 # read kml file into a string 
 z <- xpathSApply(check, "//gx:MultiTrack", xmlValue)
 # find text bounded by (and including) T and Z
 x <- strapply(z,"T.+?Z")
 # unpack the resulting list
 x1 <- unlist(x)
 # get rid of the initial T
 x2 <- gsub("T", "", x1)
 # get rid of the trailing Z
 x3 <- gsub("Z", "", x2)
 # convert it to a time format
 time <- strptime(x3, "%H:%M:%OS")
```

Comment: here are more whens than coords so they won't line up.

Comment: Yes, My tracks records and extra set of overall "whens" that is start and finish. I can strip those out first couple.

Answer (score 0):

There are better html parsing approaches but I see no one posted that.  This will work but regexing is usually frowned upon with html parsing.

```
library(qdap)
x <- unlist(genXtract(dat, "<when>", "</when>"))
y <- unlist(genXtract(dat, "<gx:coord>", "</gx:coord>"))

x[sapply(x, function(x) !identical(x, character(0)))]
y[sapply(y, function(x) !identical(x, character(0)))]

## > x[sapply(x, function(x) !identical(x, character(0)))]
##       <when>  :  </when>14       <when>  :  </when>16 
## "2013-06-29T17:09:04.564Z" "2013-06-29T17:09:06.135Z" 
##       <when>  :  </when>18       <when>  :  </when>20 
## "2013-06-29T17:09:08.135Z" "2013-06-29T17:09:09.135Z" 
## > y[sapply(y, function(x) !identical(x, character(0)))]
##             <gx:coord>  :  </gx:coord>15 
##  "-79.305048 43.710639 72.9000015258789" 
##             <gx:coord>  :  </gx:coord>17 
##  "-79.304971 43.710653 67.4000015258789" 
##             <gx:coord>  :  </gx:coord>19 
## "-79.305193 43.710535 78.19999694824219"
```

Comment: Unfortunately qdap is not available for R version 2.15.1 on Ubuntu Linux 3.2.0-45-generic-pae. Package 'qdap' requires R >= 3.0.0. Thanks for the suggestion, I will see if I can get an R version or qdap version that will work together.

Comment: Thanks Tyler but qdap won't install with R version 2.15.1:          * checking for file '/tmp/RtmpsVW5Qr/qdap-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'qdap':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'qdap_0.2.4.tar.gz'
...ERROR: this R is version 2.15.1, package 'qdap' requires R >= 3.0.0
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Tyler thanks for your suggestion. This may work for others looking for a solution who can use R version 3.0.